# Mongoose updateOne (without using $set) set array of subdocs to [] (erase every subdocs in array)

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

Example: 
a document in User collection:

```
name: 'Foo', //type string
address: [5bf2d3008af5910530e83a64, 5bf2d3008af5910530e83a64] //[{type ObjectId ref 'Address'}]
```

After exec User.updateOne : //with req.body.name = 'Bar'

```
document:
name: 'Bar',
address: []
```

ps: I dont want to use $set when it automatically add 'null' to every empty fields

Comment: Can you please stop prefixing your questions here with "Bug?" because none of them will be such a thing anyway. Show your schema and the actual update. More to the point, show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your issue and the expected result of your actions. Bugs in widely used software are very rare, and typically only in edge cases and not in common patterns. Problems with the "keyboard to chair interface" are really quite common.

Comment: Thank you for your instruction

Comment: Mongoose's $set should not unset or reset any field that you did not instruct it to. Can you share your update operation statement?